# Connection pool takes 2 sec delay with every request

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, connection-pooling, c3p0

I've created a connection pool with C3P0:

```
@Bean
public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClass(dbDRIVER);
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(dbURL);
    dataSource.setUser(dbUSER);
    dataSource.setPassword(dbPASS);
    dataSource.setAutoCommitOnClose(false);
    return dataSource;
}
```

But when I starting tests, time of every test is "2s ***ms". So I can imagine that I have sort of delay there.

I checked the JVM and found out that connection pool creates connections one after another for every request and not using them async as it should(?) be.

How can I make connection pool work properly?

Comment: Set a valid size for initial connections for connection pool. In this way it will pre-emptively create the connections. And not be bound to the requests coming in.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj I added `dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(10);` but it looks the same to me. Maybe the reason is that it is a tests and not fully deployed app?

Comment: Yes that can be a possibility. If you are creating the new connection pool with each tests from logs you can assess that.